# Calculating the Angle of Rotation Instead of Inclination for Angles Greater than 360 degrees

Tags: ios, trigonometry

I'm trying to implement a rotary wheel that outputs positive integers - sizeof(int) - when rotated clockwise and negative integers - sizeof(int) - when rotated counterclockwise. I'm working with the SMRotaryWheel implementation found [here](https://github.com/funkyboy/How-To-Create-a-Rotating-Wheel-Control-with-UIKit) and output the radian value that's generated in the method:

`continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

It uses the `atan2f()` function to calculate the angle of inclination and does some arithmetic to determine where in the range of 2Pi radians to rotate.

The problem I'm running into is that since it's only measuring the angle of inclination, the range of output is only within the range of +/- pi.

Is there a (trig?) function - or functions - that will calculate angle of rotation instead of angle of inclination for angles greater than 360 degrees?

Comment: I have the same problem with you.Did you work it out?

Comment: @SeanChense Unfortunately I did not. I ended up abandoning the rotary wheel idea. It wasn't a critical piece of UI. Please post your answer hear if you find a solve.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I was misinterpreting the original description.

Assuming that for radians, starting at (1,0) is 0, then (0,1) is π/2, (-1,0) is π (0,-1) is 3π/2, and back to (1,0) is 2π (or 0).

Your setup is that, Crossing from III to IV is π to 0, crossing from I to II is 0 to -π. So I want to change I to II into 0 to π, then change III to IV into π to 2π,

psuedocode (assumes the range of input θ is {θ | -π < θ < π})

```
function inclination2rotation(θ)
{
    if (θ <= 0)
    {
        return -θ;
    }
    if (θ > 0)
    {
        return -θ+2π;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What I'm struggling with is that when I begin rotating the wheel clockwise (passing through quadrants 4 and 3 of the coordinate plane) the radians value goes from 0 to pi. As soon as I cross over the threshold from quadrant 3 to quadrant 2 the radians value flips to -pi and makes its way back to 0 as I reach the original starting point. It seems like I need some way to determine when to start adding 2pi to radians but I'm stumped.

Comment: is that before or after my suggestion of adding 2pi?

Comment: That's before adding 2pi.

Comment: Weird, so like, if ur a hair below the x-axis in Q3, the value is like just a hair lower than +pi, say +3.13, and as soon as u move into Q2, the value would be like, -3.13? Just trying to get on the same page.

Comment: I think I figured it out, see the edit, uses a piecewise function. A non piecewise function would be prettier but is tricky since you need to do a direction switch

Comment: Sorry, I may have not been clear in my question. I can generate values from (0,2Pi) - through one full rotation. However as I continue rotating beyond one rotation I want the values to continue to increment. With the edit above, the value goes back to zero as soon as I cross the 2Pi point and begin a second rotation. Does that make sense? Sorry again if I'm not being clear.